# SUTime in Python deployed as web service is getting restarted on each api hit

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, redhat, webservice-client, sutime

I have deployed python SUTime as a web service in  REDHAT ENTERPRISE LIMITED 7 OS. (installation was done as per the link https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime and created a server code for the same )
The python version used is 2.7.5. 
On each api call, the service is getting restarted. 
The error show is quoted below:

```
> * Running on http://0.0.0.0:9001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
bash: line 1: 11488 Aborted                 python sutime_server.py
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Registering annotator sutime with class edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [3.2 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
sutime.includeRange=true
Unknown property: |sutime.includeRange|
sutime.markTimeRanges=true
Unknown property: |sutime.markTimeRanges|
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Unknown property: |sutime.includeRange|
Unknown property: |sutime.markTimeRanges|
done [3.7 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Unknown property: |sutime.includeRange|
Unknown property: |sutime.markTimeRanges|
done [2.4 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Unknown property: |sutime.includeRange|
Unknown property: |sutime.markTimeRanges|
done [1.1 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:03 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 267 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator sutime
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 267 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Aug 08, 2018 1:38:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: You should initialise SUTime only once (it's a singleton). Initialise it outside your views. Also we can be of greater help if you share some code snippets :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use global sutime variable where you'll initialize that with sutime and use that across your code for api calls

```
sutime = ''

if sutime == 'None':
            sutime = SUTime(
                jars='path to jar folder')
        else:
            print('JVM Already Started')
```